# No puedo usar las propiedades de mi objeto

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objeto

estoy usando una function llamada "openModal" para abrir un modal y mostrar la información que recibo a travez de un objeto llamado "expense", pero lo que sucede es que no puedo acceder a sus propiedades, al realizar un console.log() me muestra undefined en todas las propiedades, sin embargo, si realizo un console.log() de todo el objeto si me permite verlo junto a las propiedades y la informacion que recibo...

```
function openModal(expense?: Expense) {
  model.value = true;
  form.value = {};
  iva.value = false;
  amountIva.value = { label: '0%', value: 0 };
  form.value.created_at = date.formatDate(new Date(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
  if (expense) {
    [console.log(expense, expense.created_at)][1]
    form.value = { ...expense };
    form.value.created_at = date.formatDate(
      expense.created_at,
      'YYYY/MM/DD'
    );
    form.value.statusSelected = statuses.value.find(({ value }) => value === BigNumber(expense.status).toNumber()); // TODO: Improve this
    if (expense?.type_iva) {
      iva.value = true;
      amountIva.value = requireValue(ivas.value.find(({ value }) => value === expense.type_iva));
    }
  }
}
```

Anexo ss del console.log

[image: [console.log(expense, expense.created_at)]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que el objeto `expense` tiene una propiedad con el mismo nombre:

```javascript
expense = {
  expense: {
    created_at: ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Por tanto, necesitas acceder mediante `expense.expense.created_at`.